# making sure JCombo actions only execute on initial selection?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I need to use a JCombo box and at the moment I am just printing messages to screen for testing. When I make a selection it works as expected, however when I then re-click the combo box to change selection I get the same message box before it lets me make another selection. How would I get it so that the action is only performed on initial selection?

```
   String[] positions={"1","2","3","4"};
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox<String>(positions);
    combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae ){
              //Display selected stuff
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, combo.getSelectedItem());

          } 
    });
```

Comment: You want the action to happen once or each time you click on `JComboBox` ?

Comment: At the moment it happens every time I click the JComoBox. I would like it  just once, after I have actually made the selection. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                System.err.println("new item: " + e.getItem());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `boolean` to know if it has already been checked or not.

---

### Solution

```
String[] positions={"1","2","3","4"};
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox<String>(positions);
combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      boolean comboAlreadyChecked = false;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae ){
          //Display selected stuff
          if (!comboAlreadyChecked){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, combo.getSelectedItem());
              comboAlreadyChecked = true;
          }
      } 
});
```

PS : The name of your boolean may be a little easier than this one. This is just to clarify.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland And the name of the boolean is incredibely long. This is just to have a clear code :). But thank you for noticing.

Comment: I _like_ the long name! :-)

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't seem to quite work though. After I have made the first selection. I would still like to have the message box pop up but with the details of the new selection

Comment: @volican I'm not sure to understand your question. That's what you had before. You said : `I would like it just once`

Comment: Maybe add the chosen item to a `Set` and check `contains()` in the predicate. Maybe use a `JTable` and `Boolean` column.

Comment: Say I change to option 2 I get the pop up message to say I selected option 2. If I then want to change to options 3 before it lets me change to option 3 it brings the option 2 pop up. With the code you mention this pops up the initial message box but if I then change to option 3 I get no message box. Do you know how I could solve it so that the message box only shows when I have just made a new selection? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @volican Ok I get it, this is an odd behaviour actually, it works perfectly fine for me. Which version of java are you running?

Comment: I found a solution by following this tutorial: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListentoJComboBoxwithItemListener.htm Thanks very much for all your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After taking onboard the answers provided and through modifying the solution given in the aforementioned tutorial, I came up with the following solution:

```
String labels[] = {"", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(labels);
ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
        int state = itemEvent.getStateChange();
        ItemSelectable is = itemEvent.getItemSelectable();
        if (selectedString(is) == "A" & state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }
};
comboBox.addItemListener(itemListener);
```